# How can I append lines of text from a file to a list in between two specific lines?

Tags: python

If I have a text file of the following:

```
Watermelon
Carrot
Spinach
Lettuce
Tomato
Lemon
```

How would I append the lines from `Carrot` to `Tomato` (inclusive) into an empty list?

```
mylist = ['Carrot','Spinach','Lettuce','Tomato']
```

I've tried:

```
mylist = []
for aline in file:
    aline = aline.rstrip('\n')
if aline.startswith('Carrot')
    mylist.append(aline)
```

Which obviously just appends `'Carrot'` to the list but how can I make it keep appending till the stop point?

Comment: Do you know the line numbers or the content of the lines where you want to start and end? My answer assumes you know the line numbers, but I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @User19437129, I added in my answer the case where you don't know which flag point occurs first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:

   file_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in f][1:-1]
```

A more generic solution:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    s = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]
    final_data = s[s.index("Carrot"):s.index("Tomato")+1] if s.index("Carrot") < s.index("Tomato") else s[s.index("Tomato"):s.index("Carrot")+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a more generic way, assuming that both the location of "Carrot" and "Tomato" is not fixed, but "Carrot" will always come before "Tomato", you can do something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as temp_file:
  lines = [line.rstrip() for line in temp_file]

lines[lines.index("Carrot"):lines.index("Tomato")+1]
```

In case you could not tell which value comes first (Tomato or Carrot), you can let Python figure it out for you:

```
with open('file.txt') as temp_file:
  lines = [line.rstrip() for line in temp_file]

carrot_idx = lines.index("Carrot")
tomato_idx = lines.index("Tomato")

lines[min(carrot_idx,tomato_idx):max(carrot_idx,tomato_idx)+1]
```

Comment: This is exactly same as the other answer , just different variable names.

Comment: Well, the generic method of the other answer was edited into it while I was writing my.

Answer (score 1):

`takewhile` and `dropwhlie` from `itertools` are made for that.

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def from_to(filename, start, end):
    with open(filename) as f:
        stripped = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
        dropped = dropwhile(lambda line: line != start, stripped)
        taken = takewhile(lambda line: line != end, dropped)
        for item in taken:
            yield item
        yield end
```

Demo with your file:

```
>>> list(from_to('test.txt', 'Carrot', 'Tomato'))
['Carrot', 'Spinach', 'Lettuce', 'Tomato']
```

This approach has the advantage that you don't give up the iterator properties of an opened file, so there will be no memoery problems with very large files.